# autocomplete, search multiple database tables/fields - Symfony

Tags: symfony1, jquery-autocomplete

I have 3 models:

article [name, title]

photo   [name, description]

video   [name, description, transcription]

Now, I want to create an autocomplete search that  will search each of those models and db fields for matching string in the input field.

Is it possible to do a search over these 3 tables?

If so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your using propel.

Its absolutetly possible to do this, but if these table are not related to anything that could result in some messy code when saving. But if you absolutely need to search in those tables, my approach would be to create an action like:

```
public function executeAutocomplete(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $q = $request->getParameter('q');//The value to be searched
  $limit = $request->getParameter('limit');//Not completly necessary but recommendable
  if(count($q) == 0)
  {
    return sfView::NONE;//With no input, no search
  }

  $results = array( 'article' => array(), 'photo' => array(), 'video' => array());

  $article_search = ArticlePeer::search($q,$limit);
  $photo_search = PhotoPeer::search($q,$limit);
  $video_search = VideoPeer::search($q,$limit);

   $this->process_search($results,$article_search,$photo_search,$video_search);
  //Process those three arrays to fit your need

  return $this->renderText(json_encode($result));
}
```

Now, the search function on the Peer classes could look like this:

ArticlePeer>>

```
public static function search($q,$limit = null)
{
 $c = new Criteria();
 $c->add(self::NAME,'%'.$q.'%',Criteria::LIKE);
 if(!is_null($limit))
 {
  $c->addLimit($limit);
 }
 return self::doSelect($c);
}
```

Finally as for the widget, i have used and adapted sfWidgetJQueryAutocomplete and it work pretty good so you should check it out.

EDIT: The short way to an embbed search field si creating sfForm wit the jQuery widget i mentioned before and leave configuration and js to the widget. You'll have to find a way to handle search resutls.
Well i hope this helped you!

Comment: Wow, thats great! I will be using the search functionality as an input field in my layout.php - how would I use the sfWidgetJQueryAutocomplete doing it this way?

Comment: @user390426 I thougt you where going to do this with a sfForm, but if your going to use ajax and an input it will work nicely anyways. Remember to create an autocomplete route in your routing.yml so to keeo it simpler

Comment: Well this is going to be a global search and include it in my layout, searching 3 of my models. I've created the action and the route, along with the model methods. What would be next to achieve what Im looking for?

Comment: I have created a searchForm() which extends sfForm(). I have then created a component, which has the following: $this->form = new SearchForm(); and in the component template I echo out the $form object. This gives me an input box, but typing in the field, nothing is returned. It doesn't seem to fire the autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

[UNION operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator) is what you're looking for.